# Block Normal Key Function

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am binding a normal key do run a function using Tkinter, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text()
T.pack()
root.bind_all('h', lambda event: print('HI'))
```

When you press the `h` key, it prints `HI`, but also it types an `h` into the text box. Is there any easy way to block the `h` key from doing its normal purpose?

Comment: You can add a whole bunch of validation for that text field, or you can change the keybind to something like Ctrl-H like everyone else does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inhibit the default behaviour, return the string `"break"`

```
def h_key(event):
    ...
    return "break"

root.bind_all('h', h_key)
```

Also, in your case you don't need to use `lambda`. In general,  you should avoid using `lambda` unless it really is the best tool for the job. Most often it's best to write a function for your bindings. Functions are much easier to debug and to maintain over time.

Comment: This answer is much better than mine.

Comment: @rassar Yours seems to be the way to stop it yourself, but this is the easiest way to do it.